# El manifest.xml de mi app no me reconoce las imágenes de la carpeta drawable para el atributo icon

Tags: android, android-studio

Aquí dejo captura de mi Manifest.xml y con la ubicación de los png que intento referenciar en android:icon sin éxito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy un novato en desarrollo de apps Android, he intentado seguir los pasos necesarios para configurar el icono de la app a través de páginas y tutoriales de Internet, pero aquí me he estancado y no logro ver el por qué de éste error...

Alguien por aquí que le haya pasado lo mismo o que pueda orientarme un poco al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La estructura de tus directorios en incorrecta, los directorios `drawable` de diferentes densidades deben ubicarse en el mismo nivel que el directorio `/drawable`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mueve todos los directorios  `drawable` de diferentes densidades al nivel del directorio `/drawable`.

Comment: Tenías razón amigo. Efectivamente, tienen que estar todos los directorios Drawable al mismo nivel, sean del tipo que sean. Muchas gracias.